# When comparing two Integer class variables that are the same, java says its not equal

Tags: java

So I have code where I compare two Integer variables, they are the same thing but somehow java says that it isn't. it prints out this to the console:

`The expected and actual don't match: java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<[Ljava.lang.Integer;@7cf10a6f> but was:<514579>`
for the following code:

```
@Test
    public void testDay_1() {
        Integer[][] testCases= {
                {1721, 979, 366, 299, 675, 1456},
                {2020, 0}
        };

        Integer[] expected = {
                514579,
                0
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < testCases.length; i++) {
            Integer actual = DayOne.find2020Sum(testCases[i]);
            try {
                Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);      //HERE
            } catch (AssertionError e) {
                System.out.println("The expected and actual don't match: " + e);
                Assert.fail();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
```

How can I get the code to properly match up 514579 for both the expected and actual? I have no idea why they are both the same type of variable but one is printing a memory address and another is printing the actual number. I tried System.out.println to see how the [Ljava.lang.Integer;@7cf10a6f> would print out, and it is also printing memory address and the actual 514579 number which I don't understand why they don't both print the number. If anyone can help I really appreciate it!!

Comment: You are comparing Integer[] with Integer value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, expected is an array. So you are comparing an array against an Integer.

Its not very clear to me, but maybe you want to compare against expected[i]?